# Low resolution and change in color of logo after rendering

Tags: adobe-illustrator, image-quality, adobe-after-effects, video

I created characters for a **Motion Logo** using Illustrator and rendered this Motion Logo adding those characters and animations in **Ae** (For this, I imported the **Illustrator** project in **After Effects**), but now the logo doesn't look as cool and perfect as it looks in Illustrator. I used the highest settings for rendering using Premiere Pro like Maximum Render Quality, VBR 2 etc (I imported the **Ae** project).

So I have 2 queries:

**1.** Is there any way to fix this or I would always lose some quality of images or logos after rendering?

Here's the difference:

A character in Ai project (Right one). Same character after rendering in **MP4**:

[image]

**2.** Do I need to create the same graphics in After Effects instead to achieve the original quality after rendering?

Answer (score 1):

You answered your own question. You're rendering to MP4, a lossy format.

If you want the highest quality, you'll have to export your videos as MOV or AVI.

Unfortunately, MOV and AVI also carry with them much larger file sizes and bandwidth rates, so it will be a trade off between how much quality you can sacrifice on the logo vs. how much bandwidth you're willing to consume.

There might be some adjustments that you can make to your render settings to improve your quality (you haven't shown us, so I can't say for certain).

**Edit**
It's probably worth mentioning that there is a [Video Stack Exchange](https://video.stackexchange.com/), where questions like this might be better suited.